# How to use linear interpolation on bezier curves

Tags: javascript

I am writing a javascript program that is to create an object, which has a direction (a triangle for ease) that will go around a bezier curve which is based on any number of points. The program allows you to add and move the points however you please.

```
for (let i = 0; i <= thePoints.length - 2; i++) {
    //fixes last line as it was weird for some reason (line before the loop)
    if(i == thePoints.length - 2){
      const lastPoint = thePoints[thePoints.length - 2];
      const pt0 = thePoints[thePoints.length - 3];
      const pt1 = thePoints[thePoints.length - 1]; //first point in the array
      const pt2 = thePoints[0];
      const v1 = [(pt1[0] - pt0[0]) * 0.5, (pt1[1] - pt0[1]) * 0.5];
      const v2 = [(pt2[0] - lastPoint[0]) * 0.5, (pt2[1] - lastPoint[1]) * 0.5];
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(lastPoint[0], lastPoint[1]);
      context.bezierCurveTo(lastPoint[0] + (v1[0]/3), lastPoint[1] + (v1[1]/3), pt1[0] - (v2[0]/3), pt1[1] - (v2[1]/3), pt1[0], pt1[1]);
      context.stroke();
    }
    else{
    const pt0 = thePoints[i === 0 ? thePoints.length - 1 : i - 1];
    const pt1 = thePoints[i];
    const pt2 = thePoints[i + 1];
    const pt3 = thePoints[i + 2] || pt0;
    const v1 = [(pt2[0] - pt0[0]) * 0.5, (pt2[1] - pt0[1]) * 0.5];
    const v2 = [(pt3[0] - pt1[0]) * 0.5, (pt3[1] - pt1[1]) * 0.5];
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(pt1[0], pt1[1]);
    context.bezierCurveTo(pt1[0]+(v1[0]/3), pt1[1]+(v1[1]/3), pt2[0]-(v2[0]/3), pt2[1]-(v2[1]/3), pt2[0], pt2[1]);
    context.stroke();
    }
  }

  //draws the last segment of the track
  const lastPoint = thePoints[thePoints.length - 1];
  const pt0 = thePoints[thePoints.length - 2];
  const pt1 = thePoints[0]; //first point in the array
  const pt2 = thePoints[1];
  const v1 = [(pt1[0] - pt0[0]) * 0.5, (pt1[1] - pt0[1]) * 0.5];
  const v2 = [(pt2[0] - lastPoint[0]) * 0.5, (pt2[1] - lastPoint[1]) * 0.5];
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(lastPoint[0], lastPoint[1]);
  context.bezierCurveTo(lastPoint[0] + (v1[0]/3), lastPoint[1] + (v1[1]/3), pt1[0] - (v2[0]/3), pt1[1] - (v2[1]/3), pt1[0], pt1[1]);
  context.stroke();
  
  
}
```

Here is said code which creates the path or track which the object has to follow. So how would I go about interpolating the points? Making sure the triangle remains on the path, as well as points in the direction of motion. (Arc length parameterization is not needed, it can speed up and slow down at certain points). The param is a number 0-number of points which again, can be any. If the param was 1.5, the triangle would be between points 1 and 2 of the path.

I have tried linear interpolation, but this only works with straight lines the way I did it, so I am not sure how to adjust it for bezier curves.

Comment: `I have tried linear interpolation, but this only works with straight lines the way I did it, so I am not sure how to adjust it for bezier curves.` So, just use the formula for bezier curves instead.

Answer (score 0):

If the final goal of doing this is to draw a curve that crosses over all these points, feel free to use [this library](https://github.com/rulyotano/rulyotano.crosscutting.js/tree/main/src/rulyotano.math.interpolation.bezier). Also, you can get the bezier segments. Checkout [this demo](https://rulyotano.com/demos/bezier).

If you do something like this:

```
const path = BezierInterpolation.pointsToBezierCurves(points, false).toPath();
```

you can use that path inside a svg, like this (reactjs):

```html
<svg>
  <path d={path} />
</svg>
```

Can check [this demo code](https://github.com/rulyotano/mui-profile/blob/master/pages/demos/bezier/index.tsx).